# Spring MVC Test: How to negate a content test

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, hamcrest

How can I negate a content test in Spring MVC / HamCrest, i.e. test for the negate of a matcher:

```
.andExpect(content().string(containsString("StringToNOTExpect")))
```

Answer (score 1):

found the answer by inspecting the hamcrest CoreMatchers class and searching for "not":

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;

....

.andExpect(content().string(not(containsString("StringToNOTExpect"))))
```